# What should i do if my fluid falls through an object?

Tags: mesh, objects, fluid-simulation

I want to make a shoreline scene, but my fluid always falls through my "floor". I dont know why (it's my first time with fluid sim). Does anybody know what the problem is?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing domain resolution. Notice resolution has two settings : one for render (= what you see when you press f12), and one for preview (= what you actually see in your screenshots).

However, fluids are designed for smaller scale simulations (like, a bathtub, or maybe a small swimming pool). Maybe it's not the best solution for this case.